# "wclient".DownloadFile in VB Doesnt Work?

Tags: vb.net, download, web-scraping

I am working on a visual basic project to download files from the internet.
Well i have a Url textbox, directory textbox, and a download button.
And YES i have done some research and i know it is something like...

```
wclient.DownloadFile(Url.Text,Directory.text)
```

but for some reason "wclient" doesn't work it says its "not defined"..? 
What else should i use or how should i declare it? Should i import something? 
Can You help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you define `wclient` at?  Can you post more of your code?  It's possible that it's not defined, or it's defined at a different scope level than you're trying to use it at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
    Dim wClient As New WebClient
    wClient.DownloadFile("RemoteAdress", "LocalFilePath")
```

RemoteAdress something like "http://example.com/sample.gif"

LocalFilePath something like "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\sample.gif"

Just make sure RemoteAdress is correct, and be aware that your application must have write access to LocalFilePath.

Comment: <h1>THANKS</h1> i found out what was wrong i forgot to add the name of the file saved like ..... `C:\Users\Public\Pictures\IMAGE.BMP` instead of just `C:\Users\Public\Pictures`

Comment: Naming an instance the same as it's type is poor practice.